# How can i add multiple columns in Spark Datframe in efficiently

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have set of columns names and need to add those columns in existing dataframe which is also very huge in size, i need to add the all columns from set to dataframe with StringType and default null value.
I am following below approach but i found that when the number of columns and dataframe size is huge this affecting my performance. Is there any better way to this in spark?
Note : Number of columns  : ~500

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
var df = Seq(
  (1, "James"),
  (2, "Michael"),
  (3, "Robert"),
  (4, "Washington"),
  (5, "Jefferson")
).toDF("Id", "Name")
df.show(false)

val diff_set = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", "col15", "col16", "col17", "col18", "col19", "col20", "col21", "col22").toSet
diff_set.foreach(x => {
  if (x.size > 0) {
    df = df.withColumn(x, lit(null)).withColumn(x, col(x).cast(StringType))
  }
})
df.show(false)
```

```
+---+----------+
|Id |Name      |
+---+----------+
|1  |James     |
|2  |Michael   |
|3  |Robert    |
|4  |Washington|
|5  |Jefferson |
+---+----------+

+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|Id |Name      |col7|col8|col3|col17|col6|col20|col2|col14|col16|col21|col15|col9|col10|col5|col1|col13|col19|col11|col22|col18|col4|col12|
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|1  |James     |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|2  |Michael   |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|3  |Robert    |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|4  |Washington|null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|5  |Jefferson |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `select`

```
df
.select(
    df.columns.map(c => col(c).as(c)) ++ 
    diff_set.map(c => lit(null).cast("string").as(c)):_*
)
.show(false)
```

Use `foldLeft`

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---+----------+
|Id |Name      |
+---+----------+
|1  |James     |
|2  |Michael   |
|3  |Robert    |
|4  |Washington|
|5  |Jefferson |
+---+----------+
```

```
scala> val diff_set = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", "col15", "col16", "col17", "col18", "col19", "col20", "col21", "col22").toSet
```

```
scala> 

diff_set
.foldLeft(df)((ddf,c) => 
    ddf
    .withColumn(c,lit(null).cast("string"))
)
.show(false)

+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|Id |Name      |col7|col8|col3|col17|col6|col20|col2|col14|col16|col21|col15|col9|col10|col5|col1|col13|col19|col11|col22|col18|col4|col12|
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|1  |James     |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|2  |Michael   |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|3  |Robert    |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|4  |Washington|null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|5  |Jefferson |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

**Comparison**

Using `foldLeft` for `1000000` records - Time taken: **18017 ms**

```
spark.time {
    val diff_set = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", "col15", "col16", "col17", "col18", "col19", "col20", "col21", "col22").toSet
    val df = (1 to 1000000).toDF
    diff_set.foldLeft(df)((ddf,c) => ddf.withColumn(c,lit(null).cast("string"))).show(false)
}
```

Using `crossJoin` for `1000000` records - Time taken: **13224 ms**

```
spark.time {
    val diff_set = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", "col15", "col16", "col17", "col18", "col19", "col20", "col21", "col22").toSet
    val df = (1 to 1000000).toDF
    val dfb = Seq(("null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null")).toDF(diff_set.toList:_*)
    df.crossJoin(dfb).show(false)
}
```

Using `select` for `1000000` records - Time taken: **8519 ms**

```
spark.time {
    val diff_set = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", "col15", "col16", "col17", "col18", "col19", "col20", "col21", "col22").toSet
    val df = (1 to 1000000).toDF
    df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).as(c)) ++ diff_set.map(c => lit(null).cast("string").as(c)):_*).show
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas   :)    Using ```select``` approach performance increased significantly

Comment: I also get to learn about ```spark.time{}``` function :)

Answer (score 0):

So this is in PySpark.

```
df.select(
    '*', 
    *list(F.lit(None).alias(f'col{n}') for n in range(7,13))
).show()
```

```
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|Id |Name      |col7|col8|col3|col17|col6|col20|col2|col14|col16|col21|col15|col9|col10|col5|col1|col13|col19|col11|col22|col18|col4|col12|
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|1  |James     |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|2  |Michael   |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|3  |Robert    |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|4  |Washington|null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
|5  |Jefferson |null|null|null|null |null|null |null|null |null |null |null |null|null |null|null|null |null |null |null |null |null|null |
+---+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

This logic translates to Scala spark if you understand how to replace the list comprehension in Scala with map.

This is faster as it creates the 22 columns to be executed at once, rather that adding them in iterations as foldleft does.