# column split in Spark Scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below Data frame with me -

```
scala> val df1=Seq(
     | ("1_10","2_20","3_30"),
     | ("7_70","8_80","9_90")
     | )toDF("c1","c2","c3")
```

scala> df1.show

```
+----+----+----+
|  c1|  c2|  c3|
+----+----+----+
|1_10|2_20|3_30|
|7_70|8_80|9_90|
+----+----+----+
```

How to split this to different columns based on delimiter "_".

Expected output -

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  c1|  c2|  c3|c1_1|c2_1|c3_1|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |  10|  20|  30|
|7   |8   |9   |  70|  80|  90|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Also I have 50 + columns in the DF. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the good use of `foldLeft`. `Split` each `column` and create a new `column` for each `splited` value

```
val cols = df1.columns
  cols.foldLeft(df1) { (acc, name) =>
    acc.withColumn(name, split(col(name), "_"))
      .withColumn(s"${name}_1", col(name).getItem(0))
      .withColumn(s"${name}_2", col(name).getItem(1))
  }.drop(cols:_*)
   .show(false)
```

If you need the columns name exactly as you want then you need to filter the columns that ends with `_1` and rename them again with `foldLeft`

Output:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|c1_1|c1_2|c2_1|c2_2|c3_1|c3_2|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |10  |2   |20  |3   |30  |
|7   |70  |8   |80  |9   |90  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split method

```
split(col("c1"), '_')
```

This will return you ArrayType(StringType)
Then you can access items with .getItem(index) method.
That is if you have a stable number of elements after spliting if that isnt the case you will have some null values if the indexed value isnt present in the array after splitting.

Example of code:

```
df.select(
  split(col("c1"), "_").alias("c1_items"),
  split(col("c2"), "_").alias("c2_items"),
  split(col("c3"), "_").alias("c3_items"),
).select(
  col("c1_items").getItem(0).alias("c1"),
  col("c1_items").getItem(1).alias("c1_1"),
  col("c2_items").getItem(0).alias("c2"),
  col("c2_items").getItem(1).alias("c2_1"),
  col("c3_items").getItem(0).alias("c3"),
  col("c3_items").getItem(1).alias("c3_1")
)
```

Since you need to do this for 50+ columns I would probably suggest to wrap this in a method for a single column + withColumn statement in this kind of way

```
def splitMyCol(df: Dataset[_], name: String) = {
  df.withColumn(
    s"${name}_items", split(col("name"), "_")
  ).withColumn(
    name, col(s"${name}_items).getItem(0)
  ).withColumn(
    s"${name}_1", col(s"${name}_items).getItem(1)
  ).drop(s"${name}_items")
}
```

Note I assume you do not need items to be maintained thus I drop it. Also not that due to _ in the name between two variable is s"" string you need to wrap first one in {}, while second doesnt really need {} wrapping and $ is enough.

You can wrap this then in a fold method in this way:

```
val result = columnsToExpand.foldLeft(df)(
  (acc, next) => splitMyCol(acc, next)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

pyspark solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1=sqlContext.createDataFrame([("1_10","2_20","3_30"),("7_70","8_80","9_90")]).toDF("c1","c2","c3")
expr = [F.split(coln,"_") for coln in df1.columns]
df2=df1.select(*expr)
#%%
df3= df2.withColumn("clctn",F.flatten(F.array(df2.columns)))
#%%  assuming all columns will have data in the same format x_y
arr_size = len(df1.columns)*2
df_fin= df3.select([F.expr("clctn["+str(x)+"]").alias("c"+str(x/2)+'_'+str(x%2)) for x in range(arr_size)])
```

Results:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|c0_0|c0_1|c1_0|c1_1|c2_0|c2_1|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|  10|   2|  20|   3|  30|
|   7|  70|   8|  80|   9|  90|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: updated the answer to have a better column name. check it out and please mark the answer as accepted if helps.

Comment: Acutally I was looking for a Scala implmentation. But this helps for python.

Comment: ah,ok.. think you can transfer the same concepts directly to scala. good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `select` instead of `foldLeft` for better performance. As `foldLeft` might be taking longer time than `select`

[Check this post - foldLeft,select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487649/how-can-i-add-multiple-columns-in-spark-datframe-in-efficiently)

```
val expr = df
.columns
.flatMap(c => Seq(
        split(col(c),"_")(0).as(s"${c}_1"),
        split(col(c),"_")(1).as(s"${c}_2")
    )
)
.toSeq
```

**Result**

```
df.select(expr:_*).show(false)
    
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|c1_1|c1_2|c2_1|c2_2|c3_1|c3_2|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |10  |2   |20  |3   |30  |
|7   |70  |8   |80  |9   |90  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
var df=Seq(("1_10","2_20","3_30"),("7_70","8_80","9_90")).toDF("c1","c2","c3")

  for (cl <- df.columns) {
    df=df.withColumn(cl+"_temp",split(df.col(cl),"_")(0))
    df=df.withColumn(cl+"_"+cl.substring(1),split(df.col(cl),"_")(1))
    df=df.withColumn(cl,df.col(cl+"_temp")).drop(cl+"_temp")
  }
  df.show(false)
}

//Sample output
    +---+---+---+----+----+----+
    |c1 |c2 |c3 |c1_1|c2_2|c3_3|
    +---+---+---+----+----+----+
    |1  |2  |3  |10  |20  |30  |
    |7  |8  |9  |70  |80  |90  |
    +---+---+---+----+----+----+
```