# How to efficiently map over DF and use combination of outputs?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a DF, let's say I have 3 classes each with a method `addCol` that will use the columns in the DF to create and append a new column to the DF (based on different calculations).

What is the best way to get a resulting df that will contain the original df A and the 3 added columns?

```
val df = Seq((1, 2), (2,5), (3, 7)).toDF("num1", "num2")

def addCol(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("method1", col("num1")/col("num2"))
}
def addCol(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("method2", col("num1")*col("num2"))
}
def addCol(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("method3", col("num1")+col("num2"))
}
```

One option is `actions.foldLeft(df) { (df, action) => action.addCol(df))}`. The end result is the DF I want -- with columns `num1`, `num2`, `method1`, `method2`, and `method3`. But from my understanding this will not make use of distributed evaluation, and each `addCol` will happen sequentially. What is the more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient way to do this is using `select`.

`select` is faster than the `foldLeft` if you have very huge data - [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487649/how-can-i-add-multiple-columns-in-spark-datframe-in-efficiently/62487899#62487899)

You can build required expressions & use that inside `select`, check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+----+
|num1|num2|
+----+----+
|1   |2   |
|2   |5   |
|3   |7   |
+----+----+
```

```
scala> val colExpr = Seq(
                          $"num1",
                          $"num2",
                          ($"num1"/$"num2").as("method1"),
                          ($"num1" * $"num2").as("method2"),
                          ($"num1" + $"num2").as("method3")
)
```

**Final Output**

```
scala> df.select(colExpr:_*).show(false)
+----+----+-------------------+-------+-------+
|num1|num2|method1            |method2|method3|
+----+----+-------------------+-------+-------+
|1   |2   |0.5                |2      |3      |
|2   |5   |0.4                |10     |7      |
|3   |7   |0.42857142857142855|21     |10     |
+----+----+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

**Update**

Return `Column` instead of `DataFrame`. Try using higher order functions, Your all three function can be replaced with below one function.

```
scala> def add(
               num1:Column, // May be you can try to use variable args here if you want.
               num2:Column,
               f: (Column,Column) => Column
             ): Column = f(num1,num2)
```

For Example, `varargs` & while invoking this method you need to pass required columns at the end.

```
def add(f: (Column,Column) => Column,cols:Column*): Column = cols.reduce(f)
```

Invoking `add` function.

```
scala> val colExpr = Seq(
    $"num1",
    $"num2",
    add($"num1",$"num2",(_ / _)).as("method1"),
    add($"num1", $"num2",(_ * _)).as("method2"),
    add($"num1", $"num2",(_ + _)).as("method3")
)
```

Final Output

```
scala> df.select(colExpr:_*).show(false)
+----+----+-------------------+-------+-------+
|num1|num2|method1            |method2|method3|
+----+----+-------------------+-------+-------+
|1   |2   |0.5                |2      |3      |
|2   |5   |0.4                |10     |7      |
|3   |7   |0.42857142857142855|21     |10     |
+----+----+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: The methods are much more complicated than the examples I gave. Is there a way to do this without redefining them in the expression?

Comment: return ```column expressions``` instead of dataframe from your methods

Comment: Got it. I made each object have a method `def expression(df: DataFrame): Column`, but I'm struggling a little bit with the final syntax. `df.select(objects.foreach(c => {c.expression(df)}): _*)` is giving me an error with no clues.

Comment: also ```don't pass DataFrame``` to ```function```, pass only required columns or if you have more columns try to use ```varargs```, check updated code.

Comment: syntax wise, this worked:
`val colExpr : Seq[Column] = objects.map(c => {c.expression(df)})`
`df.select(colExpr: _*)`

I think this puts me on a great track. Thanks very much!