# Writting generic function for withcolumn in spark scala

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Am creating a new dataframe df using the below withcolumn conditions.I have the same usage of the below withcolumn conditions for other dataframes too.How to write these all withcolumn conditions as a generic function and access it across all dataframes.

```
val df = sampledf.withColumn("concat", concat($"columna", $"columnb", $"columnc"))
         .withColumn("sub", $"columna" -  $"columnb")
         .withColumn("div", $"columna" / $"columnb")
         .withColumn("mul", $"columna" * $"columnb")
```

Comment: Creating a generic function will also require you to pass all the arguments, so why not use withColumn itself.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a reusable function:

```scala
def yourFunction()(df: DataFrame) = {
  df.withColumn("concat", concat($"columna", $"columnb", $"columnc"))
    .withColumn("sub", $"columna" -  $"columnb")
    .withColumn("div", $"columna" / $"columnb")
    .withColumn("mul", $"columna" * $"columnb")
}
```

Here's how you can use the function:

```scala
val df = sampledf.transform(yourFunction())
```

See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/chaining-custom-dataframe-transformations/) for more information about chaining DataFrame transformations with Spark.  It's a really important design pattern to write clean Spark code.

Comment: great answer! +1, could you share the information links on all the design patterns in spark scala, it would be much useful for my future work.

Comment: Nice to see how to do a function like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `higher order functions`.

Check below code.

Defining common function.

```
scala> def func(
    f: (Column,Column) => Column, 
    cols:Column*
): Column = cols.reduce(f)
```

Sample DataFrame

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+-------+-------+
|columna|columnb|columnc|
+-------+-------+-------+
|1      |2      |3      |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Creating Expressions.

```
scala> val colExpr = Seq(
     |     $"columna",
     |     $"columnb",
     |     $"columnc",
     |     func(concat(_,_),$"columna",$"columnb",$"columnc").as("concat"),
     |     func((_ / _),$"columna",$"columnb").as("div"),
     |     func((_ * _),$"columna",$"columnb").as("mul"),
     |     func((_ + _),$"columna",$"columnb").as("add"),
     |     func((_ - _),$"columna",$"columnb").as("sub")
     | )
```

Applying Expressions.

```
scala> df.select(colExpr:_*).show(false)
+-------+-------+-------+------+---+---+---+---+
|columna|columnb|columnc|concat|div|mul|add|sub|
+-------+-------+-------+------+---+---+---+---+
|1      |2      |3      |123   |0.5|2  |3  |-1 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+---+---+---+---+
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026858/spark-scala-how-to-efficiently-map-over-df-and-use-combination-of-outputs/63027144#63027144) for more details.