# Update DataFrame col names from a list avoiding using var

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a list of defined columns as:

```
case class ExcelColumn(colName: String, colType: String, colCode: String)

val cols = List(
  ExcelColumn("Products Selled", "text", "products_selled"),
  ExcelColumn("Total Value", "int", "total_value"),
)
```

And a file (csv with header columns `Products Selled`, `Total Value`) which is readed as dataframe.

```
  val df = spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv(filePath)

  // csv file have header as colNames
  var finalDf = df
      .withColumn("row_id", monotonically_increasing_id)
      .select(cols
         .map(_.name.trim)
         .map(col): _*)

  // convert df col names as colCodes (for kudu table columns)
  cols.foreach(col => finalDf = finalDf.withColumnRenamed(col.name.trim, col.colCode.trim))
```

In last line, I change the dataframe column name from `Products Selled` into `products_selled`. Due of this, finalDf is a `var`.

I want to know if is a solution to declare finalDf as val, and not var.

I tried something like below code, but `withColumnRenamed` return a new DataFrame, but I can not do this outside `cols.foreach`

```
cols.foreach(col => finalDf.withColumnRenamed(col.name.trim, col.colCode.trim))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `select` You can rename columns.

renaming columns inside `select` is faster than `foldLeft`, check [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487649/how-can-i-add-multiple-columns-in-spark-datframe-in-efficiently/62487899#62487899) for comparison.

Try below code.

```
case class ExcelColumn(colName: String, colType: String, colCode: String)

val cols = List(
  ExcelColumn("Products Selled", "string", "products_selled"),
  ExcelColumn("Total Value", "int", "total_value"),
)
```

```
val colExpr = cols.map(c => trim(col(c.colName)).as(c.colCode.trim))
```

If you are storing valid column data type in `ExcelColumn` case class, you can use column data type like below.

```
val colExpr = cols.map(c => trim(col(c.colName).cast(c.colType)).as(c.colCode.trim))
```

```
finalDf.select(colExpr:_*)
```

Comment: This is better than calling `withColumnRenamed` multiple times in a loop because it generates a less complex parsed plan that's easier for Catalyst to optimize.

Comment: Following the @powers answer, I checked this answer as solution because looks more performant. But, I found a big issue. Using select with this expression, the new dataframe will have all columns with StringType. I need to keep the schema of the previous df.

Comment: thanks. Is needed to map kudu db types to spark.sql StructField types. So, if colCode is "int" this will be mapped to IntegerType (spark.sql.types)

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use `foldLeft` with `withColumnRenamed`

```
case class ExcelColumn(colName: String, colType: String, colCode: String)

val cols = List(
  ExcelColumn("Products Selled", "text", "products_selled"),
  ExcelColumn("Total Value", "int", "total_value"),
)

val resultDF = cols.foldLeft(df){(acc, name ) =>
  acc.withColumnRenamed(name.colName.trim, name.colCode.trim)
}
```

Original Schema:

```
root
 |-- Products Selled: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Total Value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```

New Schema:

```
root
 |-- products_selled: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- total_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```