What is the performance difference between different filter approach in spark?
I have a huge dataframe (lets say rows_df) and list of filters (filter1, filter2, filter3, fitler4) that need to be applied on the data.
Current Approach:
filtered_df1 = rows_df.filter(condition1)
filtered_df2 = rows_df.filter(condition2)
filtered_df3 = rows_df.filter(condition3)
filtered_df4 = rows_df.filter(condition4)

filtered_df1_wc = filtered_df1.withColumn(filter1, "1")
filtered_df2_wc = filtered_df2.withColumn(filter2, "1")
filtered_df3_wc = filtered_df3.withColumn(filter3, "1")
filtered_df4_wc = filtered_df4.withColumn(filter4, "1")

filtered_df = filtered_df1.union(filtered_df2).union(filtered_df2).union(filtered_df3).union(filtered_df4)
filtered_df_with_col = filtered_df1_wc.union(filtered_df2_wc).union(filtered_df2_wc).union(filtered_df3_wc).union(filtered_df4_wc)

good_rows = rows_df.exceptAll(filtered_df)
bad_rows = filtered_df_with_col

Alternative 1:
for each filter:
    rows_df = rows_df.withColumn(filter1, when(condition1,1).otherwise(0))

Alternative 2:
rows_df = rows_df.withColumn(filter1, when(condition1,1).otherwise(0))
                .withColumn(filter2, when(condition2,1).otherwise(0))
                .withColumn(filter3, when(condition3,1).otherwise(0))
                .withColumn(filter4, when(condition4,1).otherwise(0))

Alternative 3:
spark.sql(select *, case when condition1 then 1 else 0 end as filter1, 
                    case when condition2 then 1 else 0 end as filter2,
                    case when condition3 then 1 else 0 end as filter3,
                    case when condition4 then 1 else 0 end as filter4)

For each of the alternatives good and bad rows df can be easily figured out based on the value of the flags created.
I am assuming the current approach is slow as it applies filter sequentially and spark has to go through the dataframe 4 times (once for each filter). Is it case for the alternative approaches as well? Will any approach be more performant than the other?
Also, is there any difference between alternative1 and alternative2? I am assuming in alternative1 spark creates a new df in each iteration while in alternative2 all the conditions will be run in one go?

why not time the different methods on a large enough dataset and decide on what is best option.

check my post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487649/how-can-i-add-multiple-columns-in-spark-datframe-in-efficiently

Do not use withColumn with a large list of columns it's performance is terrible when adding lots of columns. Alternative 1 will be progressively slower than alternative 2 as you add more conditions due to this.
Using the sql() function, by design, typically produces the exact same expression tree as using the select(Column) dsl's, there should be no difference in this case between 2 and 3.
If you only have 4 or 5 cases chose the option between 2 and 3 that best fits your development style and needs.
If, however, your needs run to 100s of filters these approaches you may wish to look at Quality for management/auditing of such rules.

withColumn is just transformation and not an action, then how is alternative 1 different from alternative 2. All the transformations will be chained in the end to perform on dataframe

there are multiple sources with a quick google, but it's a projection that cannot be optimised away: https://www.aizoo.info/post/just-one-more-column-what-could-go-wrong provides a good overview.  The executed plan will tell you they are removed but the performance reveals it's more like the original logical plan.  Also note that withColumns must identify the schema which can trigger an action.
